# How do i disable scroll events for a NSTableView with a NSPageController in objectiveC OSX?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have a `NSPageController` -  the controller that enables a user to swipe between views horizontally.

The problem is that on one on the views that we swipe to has a `NSTableView` on it.
At that point I can't swipe back to the previous views, because the `NSTableView` is "eating" up all the swipe gestures. Does anyone know how to disable **only** the horizontal scrolling on the `NSTableView` so that the horizontal swipe gesters would go to the view of the `NSPageController` instead of the table?

Comment: Don't confuse people with one or more irrelevant tags unless you mean to share your project between OS X and iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in Swift with the following custom class implementation of NSScrollView

```
class HorizontalScrollDisabledTable: NSScrollView {
    var currentScrollIsHorizontal: Bool = true;

    override func scrollWheel(theEvent: NSEvent) {

        var phase: NSEventPhase = theEvent.phase

        /* Ensure that both scrollbars are flashed when the user taps trackpad with two fingers */
        if (phase == .MayBegin) {
            super.scrollWheel(theEvent) ;
            self.nextResponder?.scrollWheel(theEvent);
            return;
        }
        /* Check the scroll direction only at the beginning of a gesture for modern scrolling devices */
        /* Check every event for legacy scrolling devices */
        if (phase == .Began || (phase == .None && theEvent.momentumPhase == .None)) {
            currentScrollIsHorizontal = fabs(theEvent.scrollingDeltaX) > fabs(theEvent.scrollingDeltaY);
        }
        if (!currentScrollIsHorizontal ) {
            super.scrollWheel(theEvent);
        } else {
            self.nextResponder!.scrollWheel(theEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code for same answer for the scrollWheel method above but in ObjectiveC.

```
-(void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSEventPhase phase = [theEvent phase];

    /* Ensure that both scrollbars are flashed when the user taps trackpad with two fingers */
    if (phase == NSEventPhaseMayBegin) {
        [super scrollWheel:theEvent];
        [self.nextResponder scrollWheel:theEvent];
            return;
    }
    /* Check the scroll direction only at the beginning of a gesture for modern scrolling devices */
    /* Check every event for legacy scrolling devices */
    if (phase == NSEventPhaseBegan || (phase == NSEventPhaseNone && theEvent.momentumPhase == NSEventPhaseNone)) {
        currentScrollIsHorizontal = fabs(theEvent.scrollingDeltaX) > fabs(theEvent.scrollingDeltaY);
    }
    if (!currentScrollIsHorizontal ) {
        [super scrollWheel:theEvent];
    } else {
        [self.nextResponder scrollWheel:theEvent];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [self.nextResponder scrollWheel:theEvent];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Create a bool that allows your panGesture to action inside `panScrollView`.

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
self.blockPanGesture = YES;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:
    (BOOL)decelerate
{
self.blockPanGesture = NO;
}
```

Then

```
-(void)panScrollView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer
{
  if(self.blockPanGesture == NO)
   {
   // do the stuff
   }
}
```

If you are panning the entire tableview personally I'd put the gesture recogniser on the tableView itself... Otherwise there's also

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}
```

which handles all this for you... but I'm assuming there's a reason you don't want to use this. You can also build on this logic, for example you might want to tweak when the scrollView can drag as well, by putting similar checks in -(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView etc.

Comment: What has iOS/UIKit to do with this question?